# java - Access child property from parent function/scope

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm coming from PHP and moved to java. I'm asking myself (and you guys) if there is a way to implement someting like this:

I'm trying to implement a class/classes to create CRUD operations for many database entities. All entities inherit their functions (most of them from the parent)
I need to implement the *tableName* and *idFieldName* in the parent class **DatabaseEntity** to avoid compiler warnings.
It seems like java tries to use the parents properties (which are obviously null) because the function is implemented in the parent.

Is there a way to overcome this problem? Any feedback is greatly apreciated!

```
abstract class DatabaseEntity {

    protected String tableName;
    protected String idFieldName;

    public DataRecord readFromDB(int recordID) throws SQLException {

        ...
        String sqlStatement = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %s", this.tableName, this.idFieldName, recordID); // Exception shows this line
        ...
    }
}

class DatabaseRecord extends DatabaseEntity {

    protected String tableName = "DatabaseRecordTable";
    protected String idFieldName = "ID";

    public void getRecord() {

        ...
        DataRecord record = this.readFromDB(1); // leads to java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        ...
    }
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm new to github and I apreciate any feedback on improoving my posts :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you use the method `readFromDB`in which you refer to the `tableName`and the `idFieldName`, these two fields remain `null`as long as they are not initailized, 
try to remove the fields from your abstract class and do something like this :

```
    abstract class DatabaseEntity {

   //  protected String tableName;
   //  protected String idFieldName;

    public abstract String getTableName();



    public abstract String getIdFieldName() ;

    public DataRecord readFromDB(int recordID) throws SQLException {

        ...
        String sqlStatement = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %s",getTableName(), getIdFieldName(), recordID);
        ...
    }
}
```

and the implementation would be like :

```
     class DatabaseRecord extends DatabaseEntity {

    protected String tableName = "DatabaseRecordTable";
    protected String idFieldName = "ID";

    public void getRecord() throws SQLException {


        DataRecord record = this.readFromDB(1);  

    }

    @Override
    public String getTableName() {
        return this.tableName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getIdFieldName() {
        return this.idFieldName ;
    }
}
```